# How to center spans inside an Ionic ion-scroll

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to vertically center a "list" of `<span>` elements horizontally in an Ionic `ion-scroll`, and have tried just about every "centering" style I can find, but just cannot get it to center...

```
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller='Index as vm'>
 <ion-content scroll=false>
      <div style="padding: 0px;height=80px;width:30%;align=center" >
      <ion-scroll class="center" scrollbar-x=false direction="x" 
            style="text-align:center;background-color:pink;height: 80px;width:99%;white-space: nowrap">
          <span class='center' style="text-align:center;margin:5px;background-color:red;align=center" ng-repeat='d in vm.data'>{{d}}</span>
       </ion-scroll>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
 </body>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/amJPDSNWfCYgfcR3dWNH) is the Plunk for the above.

I have colored the `<span>` elements red, and the container pink so we can see where the `<span>`are relative to the container.

Anyone have any suggestions here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this article:

https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

It will explain to you how to do it.
It use `after, before` to achieve it along with `height:100%` for the ghost element.

The demo for this is found here:
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/gsodI

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works really well, and doesn't seem mess with any widths of containers once I made the content more complex (i.e. more than just a span) .

Comment: Great. Will appropriated if you can accept it as answer if it helped you and did what you requested.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to this

`display` `table-cell`  and `table`

as like this

**Define** your `div` `display` `table` and **define** your `ion-scroll` `display` `tablep-cell`

```html
<div style="padding: 0px;height:80px;width:30%;align:center; background:green;display:table" >
      <ion-scroll class="center" scrollbar-x=false direction="x" 
            style="text-align:center;background-color:pink;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;height: 80px;width:99%;white-space: nowrap">
          <span class='center' style="text-align:center;margin:5px;background-color:red;align=center" ng-repeat='d in vm.data'>{{d}}</span>
       </ion-scroll>
        </div>
```